# Xena user membership returning all rows

Tags: rest, postman

I am working with the [Xena api](https://dev.xena.biz/)

I am having issues getting data back from the api even though i have a valid access token.

```
https://my.xena.biz/Api/User/XenaUserMembership
```

returns

```
{
    "Message": "An error has occurred.",
    "ExceptionMessage": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.",
    "ExceptionType": "System.NullReferenceException",
    "StackTrace": "   at Xena.Web.Api.ApiUserController.GetXenaUserMembershipList(ListOptions listOptions, String queryString) in C:\\Development\\Xena\\Xena\\src\\Xena.Web\\Api\\ApiUserController.cs:line 249\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass6_1.<GetExecutor>b__3(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__6.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__6.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__15.MoveNext()"
}
```

## pagesize required

Then I found that page size was a required field.

```
https://my.xena.biz/Api/User/XenaUserMembership?PageSize=1
```

Results

```
  "Count": 72,
    "Entities": [
        {
            "Id": 1,
            "MembershipId": 8326,
            "FiscalSetupId": 7,
            "UserId": 52522,
            "ResourceId": 832544,
            "ResourceName": "XXX XXXX",
            "ResourceTheme": "theme-default",
            "CurrencyAbbreviation": "DKK",
            "FiscalSetupName": "TestCompany",
            "VCardId": 54544,
            "XenaSubscriptionId": 832140,
            "SproomKey": null,
            "PictureLastVersionId": 5427538,
            "PictureUrl": "/Blob/Public/VCard/54544/Thumbnail/5427538",
            "SecurityGroups": "Admin"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am no logger getting the error but i want to get the full results back. It says that count = 72 how do i get a full list of all 72 objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging around in the documentation i finally found.  ForceNoPaging=true which when added to the end of the request it returns the full response.

```
https://my.xena.biz/Api/User/XenaUserMembership?ForceNoPaging=true
```